# Power Automate - custom filter prevents the email & updare approvers - but no error - just shows as completed

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am trying to help a friend out with setting up a staff cover process as currently it's all paper. I have gone through quite a few templates - this ones seems to be the best solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gb_FUeRjgg4&list=RDCMUCvBYTqRx-n_8KzFO0MJlUVw&start_radio=1&rv=gb_FU...

It's actually a mult-level expenses approval form for expenses - but I am hoping to tweak it once I have the initial flow working . I have downloaded the .zip file and followed the YT guide and done all of the additional JSON udpates in the various columns. I did get an error on the initial setting up so I had to use the 'build as new' option.

In the Expense types SP list I have setup 3 groups called 1, 2 and 3 approvers. Each one then has people linked to it. Some members of the team only have 1 person to approve their request, some 2 and so on. The plan will be to have a full list of the staff names in Title which then has the relevant approvers

When I fill in the SP form with any number of approvers the flow will complete and show no errors. However, none of the approvals actually execute - so none of the usual notification emails are sent, etc. I have noticed that no matter how many types I have setup in the Expense types SP list - it will only see the first row and it's linked approvers.

The issue (I believe) is in step 4 of this flow called Get approvers. There is a custom filter which when copied and pasted is as below:

Title eq' @{triggerOutputs()?['body/Expense_x0020_Type/Value']}'

If I leave this present it causes the flow to show as completed - but then there are no approval emails / notifications. If I remove this then it does actually run the approval process as well as the various emails - but the issue that it only selects the first entry from the Title column on the Expense Types SP list remains. Also in Power Automate the status goes to 'running...' as it's waiting on the accept or reject from the correponding approvers.

I have seen other flows where the user can select the approvers (or type them in) - but I would prefer to use this above flow with the lookup option of another SP list with the staff names in the Title column and the approvers in the approvers column

Any suggestions or tips on what I've done wrong would be much welcome.

Thanks

Tried starting from scratch and going through the setup as per the YT guide - but the outcome is the same with the approvals not working if I leave the custom filter of step 4 in place